# Cassandra server is getting restarted when using stop-server -p ../pid.txt -f command on windows 2016

Tags: windows, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra server is getting restarted when using stop-server -p ../pid.txt -f command on windows 2016

The cassandra process gets killed initially with the process id present in the pid.txt file, but process with new id gets created.

Answer (score 0):

In Services, check the properties of the cassandra service - you might have auto-restart enabled. Look at the recovery tab and set no action on first / second failure.

Comment: There is no cassandra service created. I was starting cassandra with cassandra.bat. Then a java process for cassandra gets created and the same pid gets updated in pid.txt file. For stopping cassandra, just using stop-server.bat file with -p pid.txt -f arguments which first kill the existing process but creates new process.

Comment: Have you checked the content of your server.bat? If the cassandra is started by that, you should be able to modify that behaviour.